# Where is ${body_statement} defined in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

In Eclipse Luna, I want to change the content of the autogenerated methods, so I went to Window->Preferences->Java->Code Style->Code Templates->Code->Method body and I saw there this declaration:

```
// ${todo} Auto-generated method stub
${body_statement}
```

Is it possible to to change the ${body_statement} content?

Edit: @Duncan - I don't want my generated methods to return null but I want them to throw an exception that the method is not implemented. The reason why I want to change the ${body_statement} is because I want to change all occurrences by one edit and I don't want to go through all templates and inspect them one by one.

Comment: I believe this is a constant and can't be changed. It inserts either a suitable default return value or calls `super(...)`, as appropriate. It might be easier if you tell us what you want to achieve, perhaps there is another way.

Answer (score 9):

Just delete the invocation of ${body_statement} in your template

Here is my Method Body template which adds a TODO and an exception should the method be called:

```
// ${todo} Implement ${enclosing_type}.${enclosing_method}
throw new RuntimeException("Unimplemented Method    ${enclosing_type}.${enclosing_method} invoked.");
```

Which when invokded after writing

```
int foo = doSomething();
```

Generates:

```
private int doSomething() {
    // TODO Implement ScaledFraction.doSomething
    throw new RuntimeException("Unimplemented Method ScaledFraction.doSomething invoked.");

}
```

Comment: I prefer `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Comment: That _is_ more expressive. Perhaps I will switch.

Answer (score 5):

`${body_statement}` is a "variable". Click on "Edit..." at the right side of the Code Templates list to edit a code template and use "Insert Variable..." to see a list of available variables.

The `${body_statement}` variable is actually empty for new methods. If you want to provide some default-code for each new method, you can simple add that text above the `${body_statement}`.

Adding real code below the variable in that template will not work, since `${body_statement}` will be replaced by a `return` statement in some cases.

Comment: what if i just want to add an empty line as default code?